# AWS SAM Missing authentication token error on sample hello world app

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm setting up AWS SAM using VS Code on my Windows 10 development machine.  When I create and start the sample hello world application I get Missing Authentication Token in the browser.  See screenshot below.

Any suggestions on how to resolve would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're simply calling a not-existing endpoint. There is a log line in your output which states how to access your function:

> 2019-07-01 21:56:50 Mounting HelloWorldFunction at http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello [GET]

So if you open http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello instead of http://127.0.0.1:3000/ you should get the output you're expecting.

Comment: I looked at it multiple times and missed the path.  Thank you for pointing out my obvious mistake!

Comment: No worries. Happens to all of us. Glad I was able to help. :-)